# Webpage text in bold when click the form submit button

Tags: html, css

I have a web page and a form with a button to retrieve data from an xml file.
The text and font size changes on the web page every time the button is clicked, and the words will look much bigger in size than normal?

I don't know why, i have no javascript files or code included in my webpage.

I'm using the CSS file from a genesis child theme.

Comment: Can you show us your html/css code?

Comment: plz provide a link to your project or to the css and html. even better, make a fiddle, jsbin, codepen ...